# Pandas Filtering and convert to Date to datetime64ns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, vaex

I am trying to figure out a problem but so far I could not find any solution I hope you might can help. 
I have a DataFrame and I would like to convert `str` to `datatime` but there are some invalid rows which I would like to filter out. Here are two examples:

```
Out[6]:
  #  name    date
  0  aa      2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00
  1  bb      2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00
  2  cc      2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00
  3  ee      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00
  4  gg      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
  #  name    date
  0  aa      2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00
  1  bb      2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00
  2  cc      2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00
  3  ee      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00
  4  ff      fsadfi2 2ih3ro
  5  gg      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00
```

```
In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]:
name    <class 'str'>
date    <class 'str'>
dtype: object

In [12]: df2.dtypes
Out[12]:
name    <class 'str'>
date    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

`df` I fine, it only has valid dates in the `date` column. But `df2` has some invalid lines.
Let's see `df` first with the following line I can convert to `datetime`:

```
df['pdate']=df.date.values.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Works well:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
  #  name    date                       pdate
  0  aa      2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00  2012-11-30 13:00:00.000000000
  1  bb      2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00  2012-12-01 07:16:00.000000000
  2  cc      2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00  2012-12-01 09:14:00.000000000
  3  ee      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00  2012-12-01 10:05:00.000000000
  4  gg      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00  2012-12-01 10:05:00.000000000

In [17]: df.dtypes
Out[17]:
name      <class 'str'>
date      <class 'str'>
pdate    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Now I try to filter out with a very simple `str.contains`::

```
In [18]: df2_filtered=df2[df2['date'].str.contains(':00')]

In [19]: df2_filtered
Out[19]:
  #  name    date
  0  aa      2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00
  1  bb      2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00
  2  cc      2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00
  3  ee      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00
  4  gg      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00

In [20]: df2_filtered.dtypes
Out[20]:
name    <class 'str'>
date    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

It has only `5 Rows`. 
Now I try to convert and I get a nice error message:

```
In [21]: df2_filtered['pdate']=df2_filtered.date.values.astype('datetime64[ns]')
    ...:
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated; this will raise an error in the future
  #!/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-563087d6f949> in <module>
----> 1 df2_filtered['pdate']=df2_filtered.date.values.astype('datetime64[ns]')

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py in __setitem__(self, name, value)
   4370         if isinstance(name, six.string_types):
   4371             if isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Column)):
-> 4372                 self.add_column(name, value)
   4373             else:
   4374                 self.add_virtual_column(name, value)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py in add_column(self, name, data, dtype)
   5743         #     self._length_original = len(data)
   5744         #     self._index_end = self._length_unfiltered
-> 5745         super(DataFrameArrays, self).add_column(name, data, dtype=dtype)
   5746         self._length_unfiltered = int(round(self._length_original * self._active_fraction))
   5747         # self.set_active_fraction(self._active_fraction)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py in add_column(self, name, f_or_array, dtype)
   2872                     # give a better warning to avoid confusion
   2873                     if len(self) == len(ar):
-> 2874                         raise ValueError("Array is of length %s, while the length of the DataFrame is %s due to the filtering, the (unfiltered) length is %s." % (len(ar), len(self), self.length_unfiltered()))
   2875                 raise ValueError("array is of length %s, while the length of the DataFrame is %s" % (len(ar), self.length_original()))
   2876             # assert self.length_unfiltered() == len(data), "columns should be of equal length, length should be %d, while it is %d" % ( self.length_unfiltered(), len(data))

ValueError: Array is of length 5, while the length of the DataFrame is 5 due to the filtering, the (unfiltered) length is 6.
```

Saying: **ValueError: Array is of length 5, while the length of the DataFrame is 5 due to the filtering, the (unfiltered) length is 6.**

But as far as I understand in the `df2_filtered` I have only 5 rows. I do not know why does it matter how many rows are in the `df2`.

**Basically my question is how can I filter out the unnecessary data and convert the column to a Datetime?**

**UPDATE**

Based on `Maarten Breddels` I have tried to use:

```
df2_filtered['pdate']=df2_filtered.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Which seems working but when I try to use `df2_filtered` I get the following.

```
In [57]: df2_filtered
Out[57]: ERROR:MainThread:vaex:error evaluating: pdate at rows 0-5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 94, in evaluate
    result = self[expression]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 141, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Unknown variables or column: %r" % (variable,))
KeyError: 'Unknown variables or column: "astype(date, \'datetime64[ns]\')"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 3467, in table_part
    values[name] = df.evaluate(name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 5038, in evaluate
    dtype = dtypes[expression] = self.dtype(expression, internal=False)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 2005, in dtype
    data = self.evaluate(expression, 0, 1, filtered=False, internal=True, parallel=False)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 5143, in evaluate
    value = scope.evaluate(expression)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 94, in evaluate
    result = self[expression]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    self.values[variable] = self.evaluate(expression)  # , out=self.buffers[variable])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 100, in evaluate
    result = eval(expression, expression_namespace, self)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/functions.py", line 2106, in _astype
    return x.astype(dtype)
AttributeError: 'ColumnStringArrow' object has no attribute 'astype'
ERROR:MainThread:vaex:error evaluating: pdate at rows 0-5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 94, in evaluate
    result = self[expression]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 141, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Unknown variables or column: %r" % (variable,))
KeyError: 'Unknown variables or column: "astype(date, \'datetime64[ns]\')"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 3467, in table_part
    values[name] = df.evaluate(name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 5038, in evaluate
    dtype = dtypes[expression] = self.dtype(expression, internal=False)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 2005, in dtype
    data = self.evaluate(expression, 0, 1, filtered=False, internal=True, parallel=False)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/dataframe.py", line 5143, in evaluate
    value = scope.evaluate(expression)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 94, in evaluate
    result = self[expression]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    self.values[variable] = self.evaluate(expression)  # , out=self.buffers[variable])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/scopes.py", line 100, in evaluate
    result = eval(expression, expression_namespace, self)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vaex/functions.py", line 2106, in _astype
    return x.astype(dtype)
AttributeError: 'ColumnStringArrow' object has no attribute 'astype'

  #  name    date                       pdate
  0  aa      2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00  error
  1  bb      2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00  error
  2  cc      2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00  error
  3  ee      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00  error
  4  gg      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00  error
```

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors='coerce')` then filter out `NaT` rows.

Answer (score 1):

vaex main author here. Good question, and what halumpago is correct, df2_filtered is internally still 6 rows long. What you try to do with the following:

```
# Adds a numpy arrays to the dataframe
df2_filtered['pdate'] = df2_filtered.date.values.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Is to add an array of length 5 (that is what `.values` gives you back) to a DataFrame that internally has a bunch of arrays of length 6. This is what the error message tries to convey. If the error is unclear, of something else, let us know at https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues . In theory we could support this, but we'd have to create an array of length 6, and copy you data in it. That wouldn't be ideal when you work with 1 billion rows.

In vaex, you preferrably do not work with the underlying arrays (ok, sometimes you need them, so that's why we have support for `.values` and friends). Instead, the expression system tries to mimic a Pandas series / numpy array as close as possible. If you remove the `.values`, you will add a new virtual column to the DataFrame instead of an array:

```
# Adds a virtual column (backed by an expression) to the dataframe
# at zero memory cost
df2_filtered['pdate']=df2_filtered.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Vaex will happily store that expression, and evaluate it only for the rows that you have not filtered out. Note that if you print out the size of the DataFrame in bytes before and after this new column, it's memory usage is the same:

```
print(df2.nbytes)
648
```

Note: We are ignoring the memory usage of the virtual columns bookkeeping, which are a few bytes of course, but negligible when you work with 100's of GB's of data).

Just for fun, to break the illusion that vaex DataFrame are the same as Pandas dataframes, you can actually remove your filter:

```
print(df2_filtered.drop_filter())
  #  name    date                       pdate
  0  aa      2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00  2012-11-30 13:00:00.000000000
  1  bb      2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00  2012-12-01 07:16:00.000000000
  2  cc      2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00  2012-12-01 09:14:00.000000000
  3  ee      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00  2012-12-01 10:05:00.000000000
  4  ff      fsadfi2 2ih3ro             NaT
  5  gg      2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00  2012-12-01 10:05:00.000000000
```

So the data was actually never really gone, we just hide it from you :).

This allows you to work with a massively large Vaex DataFrames and add many new columns, do a lot of filtering, and still have no MemoryError. We keep referring to the original data and just keep masks for filters, and expressions for calculations.

Comment: Hi Maarten, thanks for the detailed answer. Just let me say that `Vaex` is great! Of course there are a lot if thinks to learn but it is great so far. :) So If I understand right you are saying  ```In [55]: df2_filtered['pdate']=df2_filtered.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
    ...:```  should solve my problem?  I have tried it works but when I ran `df2_filtered` I get a an other error. It is too long I can not even type it here..

Comment: Glad you like it, thanks! It works for me for vaex-core version 1.3, if not, then you may have found a bug, which you could report on https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues . If you could leave a piece of code that I can run, that would be great. Make sure you have the latest versions as well.

Comment: I have updated the original comment with the error message what I am getting now. I am not sure why is it working for you but I am pretty sure you know `vaex` a bit more than me.. :)

Comment: I just double checked ```vaex-core (1.3.0)         - Core of vaex
  INSTALLED: 1.3.0 (latest)``` ,so I am on 1.3 as well.

Comment: Yeah, you have found an bug. It does hot happend in my case because the underlying data is a numpy array. Would you mind opening an issue. If I fix this, my answer should be work.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `pd.to_datetime` which allows you to convert the column into the DateTime with certain keyword arguments. in this instance you need `errors='coerce'`

```
print(df)

   name                       date
0   aa  2012-11-30T14:00:00+01:00
1   bb  2012-12-01T08:16:00+01:00
2   cc  2012-12-01T10:14:00+01:00
3   ee  2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00
4   ff              fsadfi22ih3ro
5   gg  2012-12-01T11:05:00+01:00

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],errors='coerce')
print(df)
      name                      date
0   aa 2012-11-30 14:00:00+01:00
1   bb 2012-12-01 08:16:00+01:00
2   cc 2012-12-01 10:14:00+01:00
3   ee 2012-12-01 11:05:00+01:00
4   ff                       NaT
5   gg 2012-12-01 11:05:00+01:00
```

---

now simply drop the rows with a `.dropna()` whilst subsetting the date column.

```
df.dropna(subset=['date'])
print(df)
    name                      date
0   aa 2012-11-30 14:00:00+01:00
1   bb 2012-12-01 08:16:00+01:00
2   cc 2012-12-01 10:14:00+01:00
3   ee 2012-12-01 11:05:00+01:00
5   gg 2012-12-01 11:05:00+01:00

print(df.dtypes)
name                                  object
date    datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this gives me an error just like to halumpago, `Vaex` does not know what to do with `NaT` values.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't have a full answer, but I might have an idea for this portion of your question:

> I do not know why does it matter how many rows are in the df2.

It matters because, from what I understand, `vaex` constructs new columns by storing the *operations* that define that column (looks like they call them "Virtual Columns"). Pandas, in comparison, constructs new columns by computing, storing, and copying the actual values for the new column.

Pandas is *really* hard on memory, but gives you a lot of flexibility with moving your data around. You're not going to have this kind of flexibility with Virtual Columns, but your program will likely be better with memory usage.

Take a look at your line that's doing the filtering:

```
df2_filtered=df2[df2['date'].str.contains(':00')]
```

Unlike in Pandas, `df2_filtered` is not an actual "thing" in memory. Rather, it's a reference to the original `df2` dataframe plus some extra logic that tells vaex to ignore anything that doesn't end with ':00'.

So, when you run:

```
df2_filtered['pdate']=df2_filtered.date.values.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

you're effectively asking `vaex` to create a new column in `df2` because `df2_filtered` is actually just a filtered reference to `df2`. `vaex` doesn't know what to do with the rows that were filtered out of `df2`, so it throws the error you're seeing.

So, to do the conversion, you need some way to fill in the missing values for `df2`. I'm unfortunately not familiar enough with `vaex` to be able to help with this. I tried out @datanovice's approach, but `vaex` was complaining that it doesn't know what to do with `NaT` values.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit clear but somehow seems a bit odd , I understand you `vaex` never copies data just hide filtered data, but if you filter and you do anything on that filtered data that still should not impact the other rows... at least that would be nice :)